# How to delete a element which has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete a `input which has focus` , I don't want to give any ids initially to any input ,

```js
$('button').on("click",function(){
$(':focus').remove();});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" /><br><br>
<input type="text" /><br><br>
<input type="text" /><br><br>
<button>Delete focused input </button>
```

> When user selects any of these three input, and then if the user click delete button that selected input field should be deleted.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the last text box focus then use it to delete on button click like this The problem with your current implementation is you are removing the currently focus element which will obviously be button as focus happens prior click

```js
var s = "";
$('input').on('focus',function(){
  s = this;
})
$('button').on("click",function(){
  $(s).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" /><br><br>
<input type="text" /><br><br>
<input type="text" /><br><br>
<button>
delete focused input </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the `element` which `had focus` before `button` was clicked because when button will be `clicked` `focus` will shift to `button`.

```
<script>
  var element;
  $('button').on("click", function () {
    $(element).remove();
  });
  $("input").focus(function () {
    element = $(this);
  });
</script>
```